# MySQL Query over 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to call a headline from one table based upon the selection of another table. I have written the following query but I keep on getting an error of "Unknown column in 'where clause'. The column is there but not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
    SELECT ms95f_createalist_items.headline FROM ms95f_createalist_items
    WHERE ms95f_createalist_items.heading = ms95f_createalist_categories.id
```

Comment: Can we see your table structure?

Comment: both of your tables need to exist in the `from`.  Also you should use `JOIN` with `ON` instead of joining in your `WHERE`. The query would be `SELECT i.headline FROM ms95f_createalist_items i JOIN ms95f_createalist_categories c ON i.heading = c.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the table in a join:

```
SELECT items.headline 
FROM ms95f_createalist_items items
JOIN ms95f_createalist_categories categories
ON items.heading = categories.id
```